# Will deleting Dropbox files on my Mac affect other linked devices?

Tags: dropbox, mac

Just recently ended a job and all my previous bosses files are linked to my computer through Dropbox. I have deleted the Dropbox application but they remain on my computer, I just want to be certain that by removing that folder it will not affect any of the documents.

Answer (score 5):

If you first uninstall the Dropbox application (as you seem to have done) & then remove the files then it will not affect the documents on linked devices.

Answer (score 2):

Sathya's answer is correct. I just wanted to note that you don't have to uninstall Dropbox to prevent affecting the documents. You'd still have an account and anytime you logged on or reinstalled, everything would be back in sync.

Another option is "leaving the folder" by:

1. going to https://www.dropbox.com/home
2. logging in
3. Right-clicking on the folder you want to leave and selecting shared folder options
4. Then select "leave folder"